# How can I use CBCentralManager from other viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I have a viewController that implements coreBluetooth on my objective c application. I initialize my CBCentralManager on a viewController, but  I want reconnect and use didDiscoverPeripheral from another viewController and from APpDelegate.

If I use to init this code:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) CBCentralManager *central;

...

self.central=[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)];
```

How can I use the coreBlueooth delegates function without need reset and initialize again the CBCentralManager?

Hope be clear.

Comment: Move the CBCentralManager out into some other class and pass a reference to an instance of that class around.  You can use NSNotification to notify your view controllers of blue tooth events

Comment: See https://github.com/paulw11/BTMonitor for an example

Comment: Singleton Pattern, often with method `sharedInstance` to get it is a way to do that.